# Unity - Problems using fill for an image in a canvas using a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 images (2 players), these will be refilled each time a player fires (working as a reload animation). Here is the code for the Reload class

```
 using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

public Image fillImg1;
public Image fillImg2;
float timeAmt = 1;
float time;

void Start() { 
   // GameObject RC = GameObject.Find("ReloadCanvas");
    fillImg2 = GetComponent<Image>();
    time = timeAmt;
}

public void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        if (fillImg2 != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload");
            while (time > 0)
            {
                time -= Time.deltaTime;
                fillImg2.fillAmount = time / timeAmt;
            }

            Debug.Log("Time reset - " + Time.deltaTime);
            time = timeAmt;
        }
        else { Debug.Log("Fill Image 2 is null"); }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if (fillImg2 != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P1 Reload");
        while (time > 0)
        {
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
            fillImg1.fillAmount = time / timeAmt;
        }

        Debug.Log("Time reset - " + Time.deltaTime);
        time = timeAmt;

    }
    else { Debug.Log("Fill Image 1 is null"); }
}
}
}
```

My problem is that even though i have the images filled in the canvas, the 'else if the images are null' check are being triggered.

Here is an image of the [ReloadCanvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCttz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that on Start() you are pointing your fillImg2 image to a null. When you use GetComponent<>() you are checking the component of a GameObject which your fillImg2 is already an image.

Remove  `fillImg2 = GetComponent<Image>();` from your Start method and it should no longer be null.

Comment: Thanks! The errors are no longer appearing, however now the images are disappearing when I fire for some reason

Comment: Thats because your setting the image to fill from 1 to 0 causing the image to disappear. To have the image fill up upon firing you will need to set time = 0 then reverse the time -= to time +=. This will make the image disappear immediately after firing then fill up from 0 to 1.

Comment: Tried it there and it isnt changing the image at all for some reason. My current code is        `if (fillImg2 != null) { Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload"); time2 = 0; while (time2 <= timeAmt2) { time2 += Time.deltaTime; fillImg2.fillAmount = time2; } time2 = timeAmt2; }`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Not exactly sure about that one. I would suggest checking your image type in the inspector to see if its set to filled. If that's not set it won't change.

Comment: No worries, had to start a different thread for that issue and got it resolved. Thanks!